# Trouble Installing Homebrew on Mac

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am having trouble installing Homebrew on a mac. I am running Mac OS X 10.8.4.

When I try to install it through

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Or:

```
ruby <(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)
```

I get:

```
\-bash: curl: command not found
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

I have also tried:

```
cd /usr/local/bin 
mkdir homebrew && curl -L https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tarball/master | tar xz --strip 1 -C homebrew
```

And got:

```
-bash: mkdir: command not found
```

What do you think may be wrong>

Comment: mkdir will be a system command, but `curl` isn't installed on your machine, so the chained `mkdir && curl` is failing.

Comment: Do you have the BSD subsystem installed?